# No IDLE Subprocess connection

Tags: python, macos, subprocess

I'm new to python programming, and want to try to edit scripts in IDLE instead of the OSX command line. However, when I try to start it, it gives me the error "Idle Subprocess didn't make a connection. Either Idle can't start a subprocess or personal firewall software is blocking the connection." I don't have a firewall configured, so what could the problem be?

Answer (score 2):

You can try running IDLE with the "-n" option.  From the IDLE help:

```
Running without a subprocess:

    If IDLE is started with the -n command line switch it will run in a
    single process and will not create the subprocess which runs the RPC
    Python execution server.  This can be useful if Python cannot create
    the subprocess or the RPC socket interface on your platform.  However,
    in this mode user code is not isolated from IDLE itself.  Also, the
    environment is not restarted when Run/Run Module (F5) is selected.  If
    your code has been modified, you must reload() the affected modules and
    re-import any specific items (e.g. from foo import baz) if the changes
    are to take effect.  For these reasons, it is preferable to run IDLE
    with the default subprocess if at all possible.
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't say which version of Python or OS X you are using but, if you are trying to use the IDLE installed by the recent python.org 64-bit installer for Python 2.7, you are almost certainly running into a [known issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue9227).  As noted in the bug report, until the problem with the 2.7 installer is resolved, the simplest workaround for 2.7 is to install the 32-bit-only version of 2.7 using [the '10.3 and up' installer](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7/).

UPDATE: This problem existed with the python.org 64-bit/32-bit installer for Python 2.7.  It has been corrected with subsequent releases of Python 2.7; as of this writing, Python 2.7.2 is current.  However, the root cause of the original problem remains the version of `Tcl/Tk 8.5` supplied by Apple with Mac OS X 10.6.  To use IDLE or Tkinter with the current 64-bit Python installers for OS X, you need to install the more stable `Tcl/Tk 8.5` from ActiveState.  Updated details are maintained [here](http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/) which is also linked from the current installer download pages.

Comment: I am using 2.7 on Mac OSX 10.6.4. I'm pretty sure it's the 64 bit version. Is there a huge difference between me using the 64 bit process and me using the 32 bit process? How do I downgrade?

Comment: Crudely put, the difference between 32-bit and 64-bit Python is largely one of better performance when dealing with certain types of problems, for example ones involving very large sets of data or very large integers. Most likely you won't notice any difference.  To downgrade, just load the other installer from python.org and install it just like you installed the first time.  It will overwrite the original files installed.  If you have installed any additional Python packages already (typically something using a setup.py script), you will need to reinstall them afterwards.