# Errno 10053 with Python IDLE

Tags: python-2.7, windows-7

Out of the blue today I started having this problem.. in trying to run the Python Shell from my .py file. The shell window opens with a blinking cursor. If i type anything and hit enter the following error hits. Python IDLE doesn't work at all and I only get this error.

```
IDLE internal error in runcode()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\rpc.py", line 235, in asyncqueue
    self.putmessage((seq, request))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\rpc.py", line 332, in putmessage
    n = self.sock.send(s[:BUFSIZE])
error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

Python (command line) works fine, but the IDLE does not. I've tried rebooting windows and system restore with no luck. I've been googling for answers with little success. My firewall has always been disabled. Trying to start IDLE from command line returns the following error.

```
C:\Python27>python.exe -m idlelib.idle
Failed to load extension 'CallTips'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\EditorWindow.py", line 1061, in load_standard_ex
tensions
    self.load_extension(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\EditorWindow.py", line 1076, in load_extension
    cls = getattr(mod, name)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CallTips'

----------------------------------------
Unhandled server exception!
Thread: SockThread
Client Address:  ('127.0.0.1', 49552)
Request:  <socket._socketobject object at 0x0176BCA8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\rpc.py", line 503, in __init__
    SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler.__init__(self, sock, addr, svr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 649, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 276, in handle
    executive = Executive(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 315, in __init__
    self.calltip = CallTips.CallTips()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CallTips'
```

Windows -32bit OS. thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is really weird. But a great question you posted! Nice to read.

Here could be a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3277996/1320237

Why would it be impossible to import the Calltips module from the standart library? Maybe you have a Python 3 idle open? Then they interfere?

Comment: thanks for the comment. No other IDLEs open. I'm considering an uninstall/reinstall of python27, however I'm worried I'd lose all the post-installation modules I've downloaded (ie numpy, matplotlib, etc etc). But then again, I've already lost a half days work troubleshooting this issue and I can't afford another day. I need to get back to work!

Answer (score 0):

Well my impatience got the best of me. I copied my site-packages file to the desktop and uninstalled/reinstalled Python. Pasted the site-packages back into my Python directory and all is right with the world again.